# Redirect with .htaccess not working correctly when missing / in the end

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've **Wordpress** site with **WPML** installed. I've done 2 things recently:

- Move HTTP only to HTTPS only
- Move http://domain.pl to https://domain.xyz (English)
- Move http://domain.pl/pl to https://domain.pl (Polish)

This is done to improve SEO. However while I got that working without much problem using:

```
 # BEGIN HTTPS
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
 #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
 #RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
 </IfModule>
 # END HTTPS
 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>

 # END WordPress
```

In **apache.conf** file `ServerName domain.xyz, ServerAlias domain.pl www.domain.pl` and so on. I'm having problems with most of my old blog posts that are around the internet in different forms. For example:

- This little entry http://domain.pl/email-address-policy/ redirects properly to https://domain.xyz/email-address-policy/
- This little entry http://domain.pl/powershell-write-host doesn't. It simply goes to https://domain.pl/powershell-write-host which is 404 and that's it.

It seems that last **/** is making huge difference.

I've planned to add all redirects in even direct form 1 to 1 to new domain but since it's partially working, partially not I'm kind of lost... and I am not sure how I could translate them correctly.

EDIT:

I've tried multiple options, even one that supposedly rewrites all links to end with / and it still fails.

```
# BEGIN HTTPS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
#RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
#RewriteRule (.*) https://evotec.xyz/$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME%}/$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]


</IfModule>
# END HTTPS
```

Another update:

- https://domain.xyz/url-is-here - works correctly
- https://domain.xyz/url-is-here/ - works correctly
- https://domain.pl/url-is-here - doesn't work, isn't convered to https://domain.xyz/url-is-here/
- https://domain.pl/url-is-here/ - convers correctly to https://domain.xyz/url-is-here/

So it's not entirely not working for all slash vs non-slash. It's more about translation of some sort that doesn't happen if it points to old domain.

I've tried using Redirect Checker to see how it works (on proper example) but I can't make any meaning from it.

- Check of http://evotec.pl/hub/scripts/office365-addbulkemailaddressses-ps1

> http://evotec.pl/hub/scripts/office365-addbulkemailaddressses-ps1 301
>   Moved Permanently
>   https://evotec.pl/hub/scripts/office365-addbulkemailaddressses-ps1/
>   301 Moved Permanently
>   https://evotec.xyz/hub/scripts/office365-addbulkemailaddressses-ps1/
>   200 OK

- Check of http://evotec.pl/hub/scripts/office365-addbulkemailaddressses-ps1/

> http://evotec.pl/hub/scripts/office365-addbulkemailaddressses-ps1/ 301
>   Moved Permanently
>   https://evotec.xyz/hub/scripts/office365-addbulkemailaddressses-ps1/
>   200 OK

- Check of https://evotec.pl/hub/scripts/office365-addbulkemailaddressses-ps1

> https://evotec.pl/hub/scripts/office365-addbulkemailaddressses-ps1
>   404 Not Found

The more options I try the weirder it gets. While the RedirectChecker seems to be showing one thing ... browser is behaving a bit different and doesn't work for the first entry anyways causing 404 straight away

Edit:

If I leave only "Wordpress" data following is true:

- http://evotec.pl/hub/scripts/office365-addbulkemailaddressses-ps1
  gets 404 http://evotec.pl/hub/scripts/office365-addbulkemailaddressses-ps1 exactly as is
- http://evotec.pl/hub/scripts/office365-addbulkemailaddressses-ps1/ gets https://evotec.xyz/hub/scripts/office365-addbulkemailaddressses-ps1/
- https://evotec.pl/hub/scripts/office365-addbulkemailaddressses-ps1 gets 404 exactly as is

It only works properly if i use the correct/new domain then all works properly:

- https://evotec.xyz/hub/scripts/office365-addbulkemailaddressses-ps1
- https://evotec.xyz/hub/scripts/office365-addbulkemailaddressses-ps1
- http://evotec.xyz/hub/scripts/office365-addbulkemailaddressses-ps1
- http://evotec.xyz/hub/scripts/office365-addbulkemailaddressses-ps1/

I guess if I can't redirect it, i will leave it as it is and just give up.

Comment: Looks like a problem with DirectorySlash directive. Check this [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash), it might help.

Comment: i've updated my post. It doesn't seem to be that since directory slash directive seems to work partially.

Comment: Can you remove all rules from .htaccess and keep only default WP rule between `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress`. Then clear your browser cache completely and then enter all 4 URLs to see which one is still redirecting to `https://domain.xyz/<url>`

Comment: Did that. Updated main post.

Answer (score 2):

I've actually solved it by using SEO Redirection Premium plugin for Wordpress.

[image]

It's able to redirect broken links without /. In this case I've done it manually but I'm working on a way to do it in more global way with Regex. Just need to find proper one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.htaccess` file with the below code, it will ensure that all your directories and pages of your old domain will get correctly redirected to your new domain.
The `.htaccess` file needs to be placed in the root directory of your old website (i.e the same directory where your index file is placed)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule (.*) https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please REPLACE `www.newdomain.com` in the above code with your actual domain name.

In addition to the redirect I would suggest that you contact every backlinking site to modify their backlink to point to your new website(For SEO).

Note* This .htaccess method of redirection works ONLY on Linux servers having the Apache Mod-Rewrite moduled enabled.

And Then for http to https :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com.au$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com.au/$1 [R,L]
```

And additionally you also can add the below code in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Note*: This may not work for you not tried, but you should try once and let me know.

Comment: This doesn't seem like addressing the problem. I've multiple domains (.xyz and .pl). We're talking about weird behaviour of /. You should notice commented out texts where I've tried multiple similar propositions.